# How to fix: TypeError: relplot() got multiple values for argument 'x' when plottling a line plot with seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a `line plot` with seaborn.

Using:

```
sns.relplot(Data, x="InvoiceYearMonth", y="price", hue="company")
```

Gives me an error:

```
TypeError: relplot() got multiple values for argument 'x'
```

What could be wrong?

Here is a sample of my data for your reference:

```
    InvoiceYearMonth  company       price
0     202001          companyA      1509.40
1     202001          companyB      469.00
2     202001          companyC      358.81
3     202002          companyD      870.00
4     202002          companyE      465.58
5     202002          companyF      563.00
6     202003          companyG      1140.00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You double specified `x`: first as positional parameter (it sets `x` to `Data`, then a named parameter `x` (setting `x` to `"InvoiceYearMonth"`).
Try this:

```
sns.relplot(data=Data, x="InvoiceYearMonth", y="price", hue="company")
```